# Laravel 5.4 session token changes on every request

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a project on Laravel 5.4 and PostgreSQL. At each page request, the session is renewed with a new `_token` key and a new cookie. As a consequence, either authentication nor flash sessions message are not working.

Already tried :

- Changed laravels' cookie name
- Played with `$domain` variable in session.php, tried null, http://localhost:8000 and http://localhost
- Switched from file to array and redis
- Played with `encrypted => false/true` and all others booleans fields
- Checking storage/sessions folder permissions (all set to 777)
- In my `routes.php` file, replaced `middleware` by `middlewareGroups`

The RouteServiceProvider.php :

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

(there is no web.php/api.php, etc... PHP files, the developper remapped all these files into routes.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain is invalid. You need to look at `config.session.domain` and `config.session.path`.

Comment: `config.session.domain` had a typo, but I also deactivated DNT (Do Not Track) on my browser and the problem has gone away. Such a weird problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your browser will not store cookies for a domain without a dot. E.g. localhost. A simple fix is to add 'localhost.com' to your hosts file as 127.0.0.1.

Then you can use for example: localhost.com:8080